# Place a footer for each activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to place a TextView at the bottom of every activity by using the include... My code is below... I don't know why, but it remains at top... Although it works fine for TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

    <include
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        layout="@layout/footer" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Comment: the layout i have used is a relative layout....

Comment: I dont know why this code didnt get printed..but this is the code above the fill_parent <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: dont post as comment. edit your question.

Comment: it is not getting printed....the websites eliminates it... :(

Comment: Try and use align_parent_bottom=true

Comment: Already done tht....in both parent and footer..

Comment: Did you checked "Gravity"  ? if not try it as "Bottom"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Maybe you are using a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout? The latter doesn't have android:orientation property. We don't see the parent XML node, so just a guess

Also, you'll need to place the include at the bottom and the TextView above it

```
<TextView
...
android:layout_above="@id/footer" />
```

Right now you are overlapping both views

Another suggestion is to use FragmentActivity and a Fragment to handle the Footer, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout in your same xml code as the parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the solution.... I had to add the include inside another child relative layout...This is what i did..

```
enter code here
```

RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        layout="@layout/footer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but...for a textview it works directly without using another child layout...So why do you need to do this for an include.....????:|

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. It works fine as posted in 1st post.
Please note that when you use `layout` tag then Eclipse' **Graphical Layout** won't draw the child xml-layout you've included (in your case `footer.xml`).
At the same time, you'll get a footer like you want if you run same code on actual device or emulator.

NOTE: you might want to remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from `textView1` as currently `textView1` and `footer` layouts overlaps.